# How to calculate the circumference of the circle

Tags: javascript, svg

I have created the SVG arc using start and end angle. Do I need to calculate the circumference of that arc? how to calculate.

```
            function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
                var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;
                return {
                    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
                };
            }

            function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){
                var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
                var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);
                var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
                var d = [
                    "M", start.x, start.y, 
                    "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
                ].join(" ");
                return d;       
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute("d", describeArc(150, 150, 100, 0, 270));
            };
```

Sample Link: https://jsfiddle.net/ndmsqmao/

Using this i have rendered the circle...
if this is a  full circle mean i can able to find the circumference using the below formula

circumference = 2 * Math.PI * r

but this is not a full circle. So can you please share, how to acheive to find the circumference?

Comment: r * angle (in radians)

Comment: @JaromandaX can u please provide example or code?

Comment: Any high school maths text book

Comment: (lol) r u studied?

Comment: No. I ate my maths textbooks for lunch. Seems I gained some knowledge through osmosis

Comment: What you're after is the length of an arc as a circumference relates to a full circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full circumference of a circle, as you mentioned, would be `2 * Math.PI * r`. If you only have a portion of that circle, you can find the circumference by getting the percentage of the circle you drew by dividing the angle of the arc by 360 (the code you provided uses degrees).

Using the variables from your example this would be `2 * Math.PI * radius * (endAngle - startAngle) / 360`.

Comment: Much simpler when the angles are in radians

Comment: Well, yes, in that case you'd only have to claculate `2 * radius * angle`

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the circumference from total circle angle 360. Consider the 360 is the full circle and its ratio is 1. For semi circle 180 is 0.5. So you can convert your arc angle to  (1/360) * yourArcTotalAngle = ratio for your arc.

Circumference = Math.PI * diameter * ((1/360) * yourArcTotalAngle);

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are subtracting 90 in the var angle in radians maybe i am missing something there. But for the part with calculating the circumference of a circle that is not complete it would be the `radius * Δ ϴ (in radians)`.  The conversion from degree to radians is as follows `pi * angle / 180` or if you prefer `2 * pi * angle / 360` (they both are the same but some people prefer the other one because it looks similar to `2πr`).
So integrating with your code it should look something like this... `var circumference = radius * Math.PI * Math.abs(startAngle-endAngle) / 180;`.
Hope that explanation helps, feel free to ask any further questions on this.